# How does one use the Chegg bulk-takedown request form?

Tags: university, cheating, online-resource

Cheating in online tests has accelerated and become rampant this year. I'm in the U.S. and my institution has had all-online courses from March 2020 to at least September 2021. Many of my test questions have been showing up on the Chegg website during the course of my tests. This was much more pronounced in the Fall term versus the Spring term.

Having tracked down a significant number of such posts, I note that Chegg has a web page for [submitting DMCA takedown notices](https://www.chegg.com/copyright/takedown-request) regarding content for which one can assert copyright. I have submitted one notice and the test question was indeed removed a few days later.

For the extensive number I'm dealing with, I further note that there's a tab labeled "Upload file with links" that claims, "For a large set of links, we accept a CSV file". In this case, I've prepared a CSV file of offending links (with simply one link per line) and attempted to upload it. However, this fails and returns an error: "Invalid file type, please upload csv file".

[image: Chegg takedown request file upload failure]

I've tried this on three different web browsers, and the result is the same in each case. I've reached out to the Chegg company for technical help (via copyright@chegg.com) and received an apparently stock response which did not address my technical question. My follow-up inquiry received no response.

**Question: Has anyone successfully used the Chegg bulk takedown request facility? If so, what is required?**

Note: This is *not* a question about how to prevent cheating during an online test in general. Such a discussion would be a separate question ([example for math](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/18477/what-are-the-best-practices-for-giving-online-tests)). Answers that focus on changing or avoiding the online assessments in the first place will not be chosen as the accepted answer, and comments in that vein will be ignored.

Comment: If your problem is cheating *during* an exam, how will takedown *after* the exam help?  You need to address this with your students; even if they wanted to, Chegg could not stop cheating during the exam.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Usually, the benefit of the "takedown" is that Chegg sends you the answers posted there, and you get somewhat more concrete evidence that the students who cheated got their answers there.

Comment: If cheating is so rampant, you really ought to change the way you administer the online exams. Because you're closing the stable door after the horses have bolted.

Comment: @MishaLavrov: In my experience, they do not do that.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins In my experience, they have always (eventually) done this. It might take knowing the right way to ask them. Does your university have some sort of office of academic integrity you can ask about this?

Comment: @MishaLavrov: Perhaps you're splicing the separate "investigate" and "takedown" procedures available at Chegg. I'm in close contact with our chief academic integrity officer, and am the first to inform and educate them about what Chegg is and how it works.

Comment: Have you tried changing the delimiter or the file-encoding?

Comment: Nothing requires you to submit your DMCA notices using their (broken) form. According to [their copyright page](https://www.chegg.com/copyright/), they also accept notices by e-mail, fax, and regular post. So why not just send your notice by e-mail and attach your CSV?

Comment: The form has three fields. What does your CSV look like? Are you including all three fields, even if empty? e.g. `"https://example.com/path/to/exam/question",,`

Comment: @Jeroen: I have tried changing the delimiter and file-encoding (to no effect).

Comment: @shoover: I have tried including three fields (to no effect). In fact, my guess was that the three fields would match the individual-request form fields (URL, location in page, work infringed) but that didn't help.

Comment: @Psychonaut: That's an interesting option -- but it appears to be more involved, in that it seems to expect a legal-form letter with additional information, an actual signature, etc. It would certainly be more convenient if the automated web form worked.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question but... Chegg will provide details on uploads to universities.  Details include time of the upload and email associated with the post, with IP address I think.  Anyways our uni. has had this issue in multiple courses and exams, has gotten info from Chegg on multiple occasions, confronted students using Chegg data in several cases, and secured academic misconduct penalty as well.  It doesn’t solve the issue of the OP but certainly an unpleasant surprise for the students.

Comment: ... Chegg could simply have a 3hr embargo on screenshots and that would solve a lot of problems.